# In pandas, how to use "where" argument to query on a datetime indexed column?

Tags: python, pandas

I used `append_to_multiple` to append dataframe into 2 tables, and the selector is an datetime column. Just like this.

```
store.append_to_multiple({'time': ['time'], 'data': ['field1', 'field2']}, 
    df, selector='time')
```

Then, now I want to use `select_as_multiple` with where argument to query on the `time` field.
I want to do like this, but query on an datetime field.

```
store.select_as_multiple(['df1_mt', 'df2_mt'], where=['A>0', 'B>0'],
    selector = 'df1_mt')
```

So, it is that right that element of `where` argument must be a string, and how to query with a datetime index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#querying-a-table), you can use a YYYYMMDD int/string, or an inline `Timestamp` expression.

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.date_range('2014-1-1', periods=300)})

In [21]: df.to_hdf('store.h5', 'df', format='table', data_columns=True)

In [25]: pd.read_hdf('store.h5', 'df', where='a > 20141015')
Out[25]: 
             a
288 2014-10-16
289 2014-10-17
290 2014-10-18
291 2014-10-19
292 2014-10-20
293 2014-10-21
294 2014-10-22
295 2014-10-23
296 2014-10-24
297 2014-10-25
298 2014-10-26
299 2014-10-27

In [26]: pd.read_hdf('store.h5', 'df', where='a > Timestamp("10/15/2014")')
Out[26]: 
             a
288 2014-10-16
289 2014-10-17
290 2014-10-18
291 2014-10-19
292 2014-10-20
293 2014-10-21
294 2014-10-22
295 2014-10-23
296 2014-10-24
297 2014-10-25
298 2014-10-26
299 2014-10-27
```